# Synchronous boost light load operation and general SMPS terms

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost, converter

1. What are the differences between the skip cycle, pulse skipping, diode emulation, and forced PWM at general DC DC converter light load operations? How do they work and when do I want to use them? Page 5 of the datasheet on the "mode" pin, page 22 (section 7.4) for device operation modes.
2. I am looking at the TI LM5122 to use as a synchronous boost. Most of the time I wanted to use it in diode emulation mode for better efficiency in light load conditions, but there could be an instance where my input voltage is slightly higher than the output voltage and I need the bypass operation of the IC. The datasheet mentioned that forced PWM is the recommended operation when bypass operation is required (pg 21,section 7.3.9), but I am not sure I want to do that since most of the time I am not using the bypass mode. What is the reason forced PWM is recommended when using the bypass feature of a synchronous boost controller?

Here is the datasheet link: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5122.pdf?ts=1592150669649&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Thanks!

Comment: Please link to where you saw ALL these terms. Also provide a data sheet link to the device.

Comment: Hi Andy, page 5 of the datasheet on the "mode" pin, page 22 (section 7.4) for operation mode, and then pg 21 (section 7.3.9) when it mentioned that "Forced-PWM mode is
the recommended PWM configuration when bypass operation is required". I am just getting in dc dc converter and I am trying to understand when do I want to use these functions. Thanks.   https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5122.pdf?ts=1592150669649&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F